# How do I change screen resolution in Pixel?

Tags: raspbian, screen, pixel

I am using Raspbian Jessie, with my Raspberry Pi 2 and a 52" TV. I just updated.

Now, after loading the Pixel my screen size is about 32" and the resolution is lousy. I looked around in the Pixel interface but I cannot find where to adjust the screen size and resolution.

Please assist.

Comment: There's no monitor option under `Preferences | Settings`? Do you get any output from command `tvservice -s`

Comment: It had been removed in updates I guess, I put it back,  by editing the menu options. But the max listed display is 640x480. `tvservice -s`  lists the same.

Comment: Why don't you just run raspi-config and set the default resolution under Advanced/Resolution ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit the settings in `/boot/config.txt`. See http://elinux.org/RPiconfig#Video for additional information.

Comment: I'm going to give it to you. When I opened /boot/config.txt, in vim and read through it, I noticed, some hidden characters, and thought, hey thats, not right, and removed them. I changed nothing else, rebooted and now it works. Thanks for the heads up for the right file to look at, there was lots of interesting info in that config file.

Answer (score 8):

You can change the display resolution graphically (without using Terminal) on Raspbian GNI/Linux 8 (jessie) using following window.

Application Menu > Preferences > Raspberry Pi Configuration > System > Set Resolution.

[image: Screenshots]

[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43631863/4132380)

Thanks Darth Vader, techraf and goobering for the advices.

Comment: It would be nice to have the full answer here to prevent link rot.

Comment: In keeping with our policy regarding informationless link-only answers, if this post is not edited to contain information that can stand as an answer, however minimal, in 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki to simplify having it corrected by the community.

Comment: I've just downloaded the latest Pixel for PC - does not have the **Raspberry Pi Configuration**

Comment: My version of Raspbian Jessie (8) does not have this option, and the "Underscan" option is now "Overscan"

Comment: Mine shows nothing under "set resolution" option, just monitor default :-( no matter if Underscan is on/off.